# Laptop boots straight up to windows 8 without asking me to start Ubuntu or anything using a live usb stick

Tags: usb

I've turned off secure boot and fast boot but my laptop boots straight up to windows. I'm pretty sure the USB stick works - my laptop just doesn't recognizes it. Help? Windows 8 64 bit.

Comment: You should made your UEFI to look for boot records on USB disks first.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a problem with your boot device order in the bios / efi.
Either try setting the order in your bios / efi or use the boot device selection, depending on your make and model this might be triggert by pressing F12 during bootup. If that doesn't work look at your manual or try googling which key to press for your make and model.

Comment: I've did all of that. Added my usb as a bootable option, with the filepath to the efi as F:\EFI\BOOT\BOOTx64.efi. When the laptop starts up I hold the esc key and get the menu. I choose my usb, but nothing - I get launched into windows 8. Secure boot and quick boot are both off.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't enable the external boot drive in the BIOS, that's what happen to me.  It depends on the make of your laptop.